# Difference between training sets and validation sets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm learning about machine learning, and I've often come across people separating their data into a 'training set' and a 'validation set.' I could never figure out why people never just used all of the data for training and then just used it again for validation. Is there a reason for this that I'm missing?

Comment: This is a deeper question and is definitely not for StackOverflow. Try [CrossValidation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: Because every quiz is easy if you already know the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this, you are going to take an exam and you are practicing hard with your practice materials. You don't know what you are going to be asked in the exam right ?

On the other hand if you practice with the exam itself, when you take the exam you will know all the answers, so you don't even have to bother studying.

That's the case for your model, if you train your model on both the train set and test set, your model will know all the answers beforehand. You need to give him something he does not know so that he can deduce some answers to you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would want the model to be trained using the train dataset, in order to test if the hyper-parameter tuning is done right you would like to test it out with a portion of the dataset.

If this was done on the test data directly then chances of over-fitting is high. To avoid this, you use the validation data set and measure your model's performance against the test dataset.